# Powershell script not copying entire directory

Tags: powershell

I have a script that runs from a batch file that copies an entire directory from a USB stick to the C drive. But before that, it renames the current `Config`directory on the C drive to `Config` plus the timestamp. For some reason, in a few very rare cases, there was a problem with this process. I figured I'd start with the script itself before seeing if there is a problem with the USB or Windows, etc. I don't have any logs or any other information right now, i wish i did.

This is the script. Can anyone see something that may cause issues?

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms")

if (Test-Path "D:\Upgrade\CONFIG") { $src_dir = "D:\Upgrade\CONFIG" }
elseif (Test-Path "F:\Upgrade\CONFIG") { $src_dir = "F:\Upgrade\CONFIG" }
elseif (Test-Path "G:\Upgrade\CONFIG") { $src_dir = "G:\Upgrade\CONFIG" }
else { $src_dir = "E:\Upgrade\CONFIG" }

$dest_dir = "C:\TEST\CONFIG"
$date_str = Get-Date -UFormat %d%b%Y
$time_str = Get-Date -UFormat %H%M%S
$archive_dir = "$dest_dir" + "." + "$date_str" + "." + "$time_str"

if (Test-Path $src_dir) { Ren "$dest_dir" "$archive_dir" ; Copy-Item "$src_dir" "$dest_dir" -recurse }
else { [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("$src_dir found, could not complete !!!") }
```

Comment: xcopy works great!

Comment: Try adding `-Verbose` or `-WhatIf` to the `Rename-Item` and `Copy-Item` cmdlets.